# Properly define cylindrical coordinates in non-Euclidean geometry

Tags: multivariable-calculus, riemannian-geometry, spherical-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

I have a density function $\rho(r): \mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^+$ depending on the radial coordinate $r$ in spherical coordinates. I need to integrate it with respect to the variable $z$, for example $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \rho(r)\, dz$. However, the metric in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is non-Euclidean and in spherical coordinates is given by:
$$
ds^2 = A(r)\, dr^2 + r^2(d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta\, d\phi^2),
$$

where $A(r)$ is a smooth function depending only on the radial coordinate.

How to properly define cylindrical coordinates $(R,\phi,z)$ in order to perform the $z$-integration?

Intuitively I would guess: $$A(r)r^2+A(R)R^2=z^2$$ but I’m not sure. Any suggestions?

Rephrasing: how to compute the surface mass of a disk perpendicular to the z-axis? With the Euclidean metric, one has the famous Abel de-projection formula. How this last is modified due to the presence of the factor $A(r)$?

Comment: While removing the backticks I also changed "metric on $\mathbf{R}$" to "metric on $\mathbf{R}^{3}$." Please edit (and explain what is meant) if that was not a typo. <> That aside, I'm lost trying to understand what's asked. You have a spherically-symmetric density function and Riemannian metric on Cartesian three-space, and want to integrate density. Do you mean over some type of region specified in cylindrical coordinates with respect to the Riemannian volume element? Over an interval parallel to the $z$-axis with respect to Riemannian arc length? Something else?

Comment: Thanks @AndrewD.Hwang I used your suggestions and added more background information